# Angular Seed project, set index.html by default

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs

I am using the [Angular Seed project](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) to build a simple website. When i start the node server and enter the url at localhost:8000, it serves up the directory contents. I would like it to serve up the index.html file but would like to do this without a redirect.

I believe that I need to modify the following function and that I should change the code for the `isDirectory` check but I'm not sure if that is the correct way to go about doing this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
StaticServlet.prototype.handleRequest = function(req, res) {
    var self = this;
    var path = ('./' + req.url.pathname).replace('//','/').replace(/%(..)/g, function(match, hex){
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex, 16));
    });
    var parts = path.split('/');
    if (parts[parts.length-1].charAt(0) === '.')
        return self.sendForbidden_(req, res, path);
    fs.stat(path, function(err, stat) {
        if (err)
            return self.sendMissing_(req, res, path);
        if (stat.isDirectory())
            return self.sendDirectory_(req, res, path);
        return self.sendFile_(req, res, path);
    });
}
```

---

**Update #1**

I have two screenshots to clarify. The first image is what I currently get, the second image is what I want.

**What I Get**
[image: What I Get]

---

**What I Want**
[image: What I Want]

---

**Update #2**

Using the link to Restify below I found the following example which is exactly what I needed.

```
var server = restify.createServer();
var io = socketio.listen(server);

server.get('/', function indexHTML(req, res, next) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        res.writeHead(200);
        res.end(data);
        next();
});


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
    });
});

server.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('socket.io server listening at %s', server.url);
});
```

Comment: This should also work to server static html: server.get("/", restify.serveStatic({
  directory: './public',
  default: 'index.html'
}));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular-seed project is a starting point for the client, but not really for the server side.
They included a simple web-server node script without dependencies. This way you don't need npm or other modules.

For the server side you can use node with [connect](http://senchalabs.org/connect)/[express](http://expressjs.com) or any other web server/language.
You just need to make rest services and serve some static html.

Since you have already installed Node [restify](http://mcavage.github.io/node-restify/) may be something for you.

**Update**: I created a basic sample for using the angular-seed with restify:
https://github.com/roelandmoors/restify-angular-seed

Comment: Great answer and you even provided a link! I even found a concrete example of what I need to do using Socket.IO. Thank you so much.